# Problems adding MapBox Navigation to my Android Studio project

Tags: java, android, user-interface, navigation, mapbox

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQPOd.jpg)

build.gradle(project) file as follows

buildscript {
repositories {

```
    google()
    mavenCentral()

    maven { url 'https://mapbox.bintray.com/mapbox' }


    maven {
        url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'

        authentication {
            basic(BasicAuthentication)
        }
        credentials {
            username = "mapbox"
            password = project.properties['MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN'] ?: ""
        }
    }
    jcenter()

}
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2"

}
```

}
and build.gradle(module) file as follows

```
implementation 'com.mapbox.navigator:mapbox-navigation-native:7.0.0'
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.42.6'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-places-v9:0.12.0'
```

Comment: After upgrading gradle to -7.0+- . Needs to do these.
1. Remove `targetSdkVersion 30` line  also  remove if any module
2. Remove *buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"*  line  ,also  remove if any module
3. Update `compileSdkVersion 31`
4. Remove `center()` line from  project level gradle
5. Find replacement of all lib that made from `jcenter()`  use `mavenCentral()` from now.
6. Update each library to the newest version.

Answer (score -1):

change your classpath  to the following version:

> build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3"
}
```

And, inside your gradle-wrapper.properties, change distributionUrl to the following verison:

> gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-bin.zip
```

and finally, add the following dependencies file for mapbox sdk in build.gradle as follow:

> build.gradle

```
dependencies {
//mapbox
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.6.1'
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation-ui:0.42.6'

//FusedLocationProviderClient
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0"

}
```